# Why does CSS3 transition not work on an element when its wrapper's `display` is toggled?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to make a dialog box for one of my web app. I have the concept implemented at http://jsbin.com/etuyut/2/edit.

I would like to have the dialog box come in with animation.

I understood that going out (hiding) of the dialog with animation is not possible as the wrapper's `display` becomes `none`. I would like to know what is the problem with bringing in (showing) of the dialog.

I use ZeptoJS for front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Whey? Well this is whey...

http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=46498

- While fading in, change display to block, THEN increase opacity to 1.0
- While fading out, decrease opacity to 0.0, THEN change display to none
- Before next fade in, change display to block once again...

Fading is pretty routine job, nothing impossible in it. Let me know if you need help with code after going through the link above. I think this is enough to push you in the right direction for now.

Comment: 'Whey'... ha ha... my typo... :D... Well I understood how to recover from it. But I was more curious to know the reason behind it. When I add class `show` to the `div.wrapper` which does two things - 1. make the `display` of wrapper as `block` and make the `transform` of the `div.content` (which the child of wrapper) to `scale(1,1)` with the `transition` set prior. Does this not work sequentially when doing in CSS?